# $ionicLoading is not showing on controller load first method

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am loading data from server by calling `init()` method in angular .I am using `$ionicLoading.show();` for loader but it is not showing on loading time. 
I am able to get data from server successfully but loader is not showing.

I tried with `angular.element(document).ready(function () { });.`
But still loader is not visible for me.
I need some data on page load itself.

sample code :

```
angular.module('App.controllers').controller('WorkoutCtrl', function ($scope,$state,$ionicModal,serviceEngine,$ionicPopup,$rootScope,$ionicLoading,$location) {

    var init = function(){ 
        $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...</p>'}); 
        if(deviceApi.checkConnectionStatus() === 'online'){
            console.log('We are inside online');
                 serviceEngine.getMethod()//server call
                    .success(function(data,status,headers){
                        $ionicLoading.hide(); 
                    })
                    .error(function(){
                        $ionicLoading.hide(); 
                    }) 
        }else{
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $ionicPopup.alert({title: 'ERROR',template: 'Application is offline. Check your network connection.'});   
        } 

    }

    init();
```

Comment: please give some code snippet

Comment: You could try to call `$ionicLoading.show();` in an AngularJS's `run` block.

Comment: Its working on click event but not working on any of page load event.

Comment: May be because it will hiding from somewhere else...Check you working flow one bye one

Answer (score 0):

write ionicLoading.show outside the init function.

**example:**

```
angular.module('App.controllers').controller('WorkoutCtrl', function ($scope,$state,$ionicModal,serviceEngine,$ionicPopup,$rootScope,$ionicLoading,$location) {



  $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<div class="icon ion-loading-a"></div> Loading... ',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 500,
            showDelay: 100
        });


    var init = function(){ 

        if(deviceApi.checkConnectionStatus() === 'online'){
            console.log('We are inside online');
                 serviceEngine.getMethod()//server call
                    .success(function(data,status,headers){
                        $ionicLoading.hide(); 
                    })
                    .error(function(){
                        $ionicLoading.hide(); 
                    }) 
        }else{
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $ionicPopup.alert({title: 'ERROR',template: 'Application is offline. Check your network connection.'});   
        } 

    }

    init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following, this should work for you:

```
angular.module('App.controllers').controller('WorkoutCtrl', WorkoutCtrl);
 WorkoutCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicModal', 'serviceEngine', '$ionicPopup', '$rootScope', '$ionicLoading', '$location'];

 function WorkoutCtrl ($scope, $state, $ionicModal, serviceEngine, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $location) {
    var init = function () {
        $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading...',
        animation: 'fade-out',
        showBackdrop: false,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 500,
      });
      if(deviceApi.checkConnectionStatus() === 'online'){
            console.log('We are inside online');
                 serviceEngine.getMethod()
                 .then(function (data,status,headers) { // DO SOMETHING WITH DATA

                  })
                  .catch(function () { // Error Handling

                  })
                  .finally(function () { // Finally close the Loader
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                  });
        }else{
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $ionicPopup.alert({title: 'ERROR',template: 'Application is offline. Check your network connection.'});   
      }
    }


    init();
}
```

I've moved code to hide the loader to finally, however, you can do it in then or catch. I prefer to organize my service calls this way, **Then**: Do something with data from service call, **Catch**: Handle the error, **Finally**: do the cleanup stuff.

Comment: Are you getting the console.log on console ? Any javascript error ?

Comment: @VishalSingh - there might be issue with some part of your code, I just created a codepen with your partial code, and seems to be working fine : http://codepen.io/ravishtiwari/pen/vLRwjx have a look

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem ( $ionicLoading.hide() not working ) when I implemented localStorage cache in my App. I have debugged with lots of console.logs everywhere because I had not a single error on the console. I came the the conclusion that retrieving cached data was so quick that $ionicLoading.hide() finishes execution before $ionicLoading.show().

What solved for me was: $timeout( function(){ $ionicLoading.hide()},100);
I have seen this hack before on Titanium with Android, so I guess it has something to do with the way Android code is processed...

EDIT

If you do $ionicLoading.show({delay:100}) and then $ionicLoading.hide() it works, I mean, if the two calls are done very fast ( less then 100ms ) loading is never show, what is supposed to be expected.
I think that the show call is registered and the hide call cancels it. Obviously! But when you do not use the delay option, the show call spends some time executing itself (async, my guess) while the hide call gets executed (and hides nothing) resulting loading to stay opened forever.